# How can I export a single kubectl context?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

How can I export a single kubectl context?

My current kubectl config file has multiple contexts defined, and it would be  tedious manual process to try isolate the single context from the rest.

Is this supported?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`kubectl config view --minify`  will remove all information not used by current-context from the output

Comment: Please cleose off-topic questions. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Comment: "software tools commonly used by programmers; and is" seems to cover the case of kubectl?

Comment: yea,  I agree, its also a practical and relevant question.

Comment: You missed the other part: *"and is ... a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"*.

Answer (score 5):

I find the previous answer incomplete. To extract a context fron the current configuration file you may use the following command and flags.

> kubectl config view --minify --flatten --context=mycontext >
> mycontext.ctx

Comment: you may want to add `--raw` so it doesn't replace certificates with "DATA+OMITTED"